# JSF Ajax - trigger on partially completed field

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I want to implement a "typeahead" type of functionality but for  effiency reasons to avoid return a list of possibly thousands of entries, I only want to fire the request to the server when the user has entered at least three characters. I.E. on the 3rd keypress, I want to call my server side search via ajax.

I'm not looking for a full runnable example, just a sketch of how this might be possible, as I'm a bit stumped by it.

I do have a generic ajax handler js file in my app to render the ajax "spinner" so I thought I might be able to hook into event method for status="begin" and somehow abort the request if the input field has less than 3 characters but I don't see how that's possible.

I'm hoping a certain JSF guru might be able to point me in the right direction :)

I'm using standard reference JSF2, no 3rd party libraries...

Comment: Just saying that instead of min 3 chars you better consider a delay (using `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`) that way you wont send ajax on every keyup , instead you will do it 500 miliseconds after last keyup... better UX IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding a `onkeyup="myFunction(event)"` to your input

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(event)">
```

and in js add the following

```
function myFunction(e){
  if (e.target.value && e.target.value.length > 2) {
    alert('do some ajax with the value: ' + e.target.value);
  }
}
```

In jsf you can add some hidden input with `f:ajax` and trigger it from js with somethign like this `document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();`
[Online example](http://jsbin.com/tuxuraze/1/edit)

Comment: Sounds like a plan, A Sneaky plan. I like it! I really need to be more imaginitive with my javaScript... I'll accept when I get a chance to play with it later today, right now, I have other fish to fry...

Comment: meh, I couldn't wait till I fixed this other urgent issue so I gave it a try - yep. works like a treat. I'm kicking myself that I didn;t think of this, but we've only recently started using Ajax. (a somewhat pathetic excuse I know!) A similar "click another thing to fire the ajax" technique could well hep me with another issue I have. Thanks very much :)